# Get range in multiplication of 5

Tags: c#

I have a number. For instance, my number is `19` . Then I want to populate my drop down with range in multiplication of 5. So my dropdownlist will consist of items of:
`1-5`
`6-10`
`11-15`
`16-19`

I tried modulus and division, however, I can't seems to get the range. Is there a fixed method?

Sample code

```
List<string> range = new List<string>();
int number = 19;
int numOfOccur = (19/5);

for (int i = 1; i < numOfOccur ; i++)
{
range.Add(i + " - " + (i * 5))
}
```

Comment: I think you should clarify your question a bit with examples of what you have tried so far, and what output you are expecting. See [how to ask a question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: division didn't work ?  if you tried to divide the number by 5 and used `Math.ceil` to round it up, and `for` looped to generate the range, didn't work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometime I think that old school code, without fancy linq is a bit more clear

```
int maximum = 19;
int multiple = 5;
int init = 1;
while (init + multiple <= maximum )
{
    string addToDDL = init.ToString() + "-" + (init + multiple - 1).ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(addToDDL);
    init += multiple;
}
if(init <= maximum)
{
    string last = init.ToString() + "-" + maximum.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(last);
}
```

Comment: Old methods are the best. Cheers, mate.

Comment: Sorry, but for the *generalized* solution you've provided, there's a *counter example*: `int maximum = 21;` your routine returns `{1-5; 6-10; 11-15; 16-21}` ranges when `{1-5; 6-10; 11-15; 16-20; 21-21}` is expected

Comment: @DmitryBychenko you are correct, a quick fix should be the enough

Answer (score 0):

*Linq* solution (modern techs allow us to put it consize):

```
  int number = 19;
  int div = 5;

  List<string> range = Enumerable
    .Range(0, number / div + (number % div == 0 ? 0 : 1))
    .Select(i => $"{i * div + 1} - {Math.Min((i + 1) * div, number)}")
    .ToList();
```

Test

```
  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, range));
```

Returns

```
  1 - 5
  6 - 10
  11 - 15
  16 - 19
```

When using modulo arithmetics, do not forget about *remainders*: you have an error in `int numOfOccur = (19/5);` line. It should be

```
  int numOfOccur = 19 / 5 + (19 % 5 == 0 ? 0 : 1);
```

for the last *incomplete* `16 - 19` range to be proceeded.

Comment: I like your solution but I think you have proved my point. It is not so understandable at first glance. (At least for me)

Comment: @Steve: you're quite right, for the question as it put (*small* collection of intervals), your answer is better then mine: your code is more *readable* which in the context of the question matters most.

Answer (score -3):

1. Add this package to your project : https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive/
2. Then you can do this:

   ```
   IEnumerable<IList<int>> buffers2 = Enumerable.Range(1, 19).Buffer(5);
   IList<int>[] result2 = buffers2.ToArray();
   // { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }, ...
   ```

Don't forget to add System.Interactive namespace to your using block.

Comment: there is no need to install a additional framework to solve this -1

Comment: There is no need to install an additional framework to solve any problem. It's a matter of convenience. And starting with .NET Core you will have to install a package even for any simple code. I don't get the down votes. My solution is the most readable one here.